# *noob* LaTeXiT long division

Tags: math-mode, packages, latexit

Like it says in the title I'm a complete noob trying to get LaTeXiT to do a simple long division sum.

I've installed the complete latex package I've obtained from here https://tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html

Like it says I'm a complete noob I need someone to walk me through this step-by-step I'm not familiar with any of the code etc..

I'm already way behind on all my work.

Thanks Brett

Picture of what the output should look like:
[image]

Comment: PS: I'd like to make it do the long division in an 'array' style I guess thats what its called? By that I mean I don't wanna have it solve the sum for me except I'd like to type out the sum myself in steps and export a pdf of each step.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Can you add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22774/124842 , https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32827/124842 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3262/124842

Comment: Instead of a rant, it would be better if you posted what you've already tried.  Are you trying long division of integers, or polynomials?  Do any of the "Related" links to the right help?  But really, LaTeX is best at typesetting when you already have the material.  But it is a programming language, so it can be forced to do whatever calculations you need, long division being one of them.

Comment: Can you maybe post a picture of what the output should look like? In the title you talk about division, in the question you talk about sum? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Are you using the longdivision or longdiv packages, or doing it from scratch?

Comment: Hi Yeah I'm trying to do polynomial long division from scratch

Comment: In answer to your implied question "Why is LaTeX considered so awesome by such a large group of people, but seems so difficult to use for a beginner?", I recommend checking out [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1756/why-should-i-use-latex).  Additionally, I think you will find that not only is LaTeX quite powerful and useful as you learn more about it, you will also find that it becomes easier over time.  Plus, look at this great community willing to help you!

Comment: I am downvoting, given the general tone of rudeness emanating from the angry OP, both here and in the comments to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

What you are writing seems to be close to a tabular. Why don't you go for an easy approach:

```
\documentclass[pagesize, english]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel, array, booktabs, ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{*{8}{>{\Centering}p{1cm}}}
  & & & $+x^4$ & $+x^3$ & & & $+1$\\\midrule
  $+x^7$ & $+x^6$ & $+x^5$ & & & $+x^2$ &$+x$ & \\
  $+x^7$ &  & $+x^5$ & $+x^4$ & & $+x^2$ &$+x$ & \\\cmidrule{1-4}
  \multicolumn{8}{l}{\dots}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

And so on... Beware, I've no idea about mathematics! You'll get the manual of any package by `texdoc packagename`on the command line.

[image: division as a tabular]

Answer (score 2):

It is not ideal, because `tabstackengine` does not have cell underlining/fill facilities built in. (see **ADDENDUM** for the beginnings of a remedy to that)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine,mathtools}
\stackMath
\setstacktabbedgap{1.5ex}
\setstackgap{S}{3pt}
\newcommand\showdiv[1]{\smash{\raisebox{1.5pt}{\scalebox{1.15}{)}}}#1}
\newcommand\laprule[1]{\rlap{\rshift\smash{\rule[-1pt]{#1}{.5pt}}}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\rshift[1][0pt]{\hspace{\dimexpr#1+\tabbed@gap\relax}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\[
\tabbedShortstack[r]{
&  &  &  & +x^4 & +x^3 & &  & +1\\
\laprule{188pt}&&&&&&&&\\
x^3 + x + 1 & \showdiv{{+}x^7} & +x^6 & +x^5 &&&+x^2 & +x & \\
& +x^7 && +x^5 & +x^4&&&&\\
\laprule{97pt}&&&&&&&&\\
&& +x^6 && +x^4 &&&&\\
&& +x^6 && +x^4 & +x^3&&&\\
&\laprule{94pt}&&&&&&&\\
&&&&& +x^3 & +x^2 & +x&\\
&&&&& +x^3 && +x  &+1\\
&&&&\laprule{84pt}&&&&\\
&&&&&& +x^2 &  &+1
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**

I've been meaning, for a while, to create the TABstack equivalent of `\hline` and `\cline`.  This will alleviate the need to estimate actual lengths for lapped underlines.  This seemed like a good problem on which to start.  I have, for the moment, built the underlying `\TABrule` which, at this time needs to be called in each field where it is used.  Eventually, I hope to be able to build a `\TABhline` and `\TABcline` which will construct a string of `\TABrule&` combinations to make the syntax shorter.  But here it is so far.  If successful, I will implement into the `tabstackengine` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine,mathtools}
\stackMath
\setstacktabbedgap{1.5ex}
\setstackgap{S}{3pt}
\newcommand\showdiv{\llap{\smash{\raisebox{1.8pt}{\scalebox{1}[1.2]{)}}}}}
\newcommand\laprule[1]{\rlap{\rshift\smash{\rule[-1pt]{#1}{.5pt}}}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\rshift[1][0pt]{\hspace{\dimexpr#1+\tabbed@gap\relax}}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\def\trao{0pt}
\newcommand\TABrule[1][\trao]{%
  \ifnum1=\value{TABcolindex@}\relax%
    \makebox[\TABwd{\theTABcolindex@}][l]{%
      \rule[\trao]{\dimexpr\TABwd{\theTABcolindex@}+.5\dimexpr\TAB@gap\relax}{\fboxrule}}%
  \else%
    \ifnum\TABcells{1}=\value{TABcolindex@}\relax%
      \makebox[\TABwd{\theTABcolindex@}][r]{%
        \rule[\trao]{\dimexpr\TABwd{\theTABcolindex@}+.5\dimexpr\TAB@gap\relax}{\fboxrule}}%
    \else%
      \makebox[\TABwd{\theTABcolindex@}][c]{%
        \rule[\trao]{\dimexpr\TABwd{\theTABcolindex@}+1.\dimexpr\TAB@gap\relax}{\fboxrule}}%
    \fi%
  \fi%
}
\newcommand\set@TABrule@gap[1]{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{D}{\def\TAB@gap{\tabbed@gap}}{%
      \ifstrequal{#1}{A}{\def\TAB@gap{0pt}}{\def\TAB@gap{\tabular@gap}}%
  }%
}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\@TAB@stack}{\bgroup}{\bgroup\set@TABrule@gap{#3}}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@TABstackonunder}{\bgroup}{\bgroup\set@TABrule@gap{#4}}{}{}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\[
\tabbedShortstack[r]{
&  &  &  & +x^4 & +x^3 & &  & +1\\
&\TABrule&\TABrule&\TABrule&\TABrule&\TABrule&\TABrule&\TABrule&\TABrule\\
x^3 + x + 1 & \showdiv{+}x^7 & +x^6 & +x^5 &&&+x^2 & +x & \\
& +x^7 && +x^5 & +x^4&&&&\\
&\TABrule&\TABrule&\TABrule&\TABrule&&&&\\
&& +x^6 && +x^4 &&&&\\
&& +x^6 && +x^4 & +x^3&&&\\
&&\TABrule&\TABrule&\TABrule&\TABrule&&&\\
&&&&& +x^3 & +x^2 & +x&\\
&&&&& +x^3 && +x  &+1\\
&&&&&\TABrule&\TABrule&\TABrule&\TABrule\\
&&&&&& +x^2 &  &+1
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi I'm not using terminal I'm using Latexit. When I copy the code you'd posted into Latexit it just gives me a bunch of errors.
It says misplaced alignment tab character & a bunch of times as well as undefined controls sequence.

Comment: Perhaps you guys could give me a simple code and we could see if this stupid thing does anything useful at all? Maybe go from there?

Comment: I tried posting this simple code in it and it won't work even then it just gives me a bunch of errors.


                 \documentclass{article}
                \begin{document}
                 Small is beautiful.
                \end{document}

Comment: @Brett Since you are using [LaTeXiT](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/17889/latexit), which claims to allow you to write LaTeX "without bothering with file creation, preambles, and so on", you have to edit the preferences [as suggested in this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87109/latexit-not-rendering-properly) to get the correct setup to match these suggested answers.  Alternatively, you could use [ShareLaTeX](https://www.sharelatex.com), [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/), or install [another editor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides).

Comment: @Brett For example, I copied and pasted your simple example into ShareLaTeX and compiled with no errors.

Comment: Hi its on auto when I paste the code into it it says Latex can fly be used in preamble.
\documentclass{article} \begin{document} Small is beautiful. \end{document}

Comment: If I have it on Text mode and paste this code in it it works 
\begin{equation} \label{xx}
x^2 - 5 x + 6 = 0
\end{equation}

Comment: Somebody please help I'm overdue on all my work :(

Comment: @Brett While I understand how frustrating not understanding something can be, that does not make it useless.  An unwillingness to learn will always make something harder, and take longer.  Therefore, please take the time to be patient and kind to us also as we help you.  As for ShareLaTeX, simply click on [Register](https://www.sharelatex.com/register) to create a free account.  On the welcome page, you will find links to their [templates](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates) and [LaTeX Documentation](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn), which would be a good place for you to start.

Comment: @Brett Once you have started your first empty project, I think you will find that copying and pasting Steven B. Segletes' answer does what you have requested quite well.  If so, at that point it would be appropriate to accept it.

Comment: Hi everybody I've had to change/update the picture of what I need my output to look like.
I've been able to get something close to this actually working for me in Latexit using the following code:


$x - 2\mathop{\left){\vphantom{1{x + 5 - 4}}}\right.
\!\!\!\!\overline{\,\,\,\vphantom 1{{x + 5 - 4}}}}
\limits^{\displaystyle{2 + 6}\hfill}$

However the numbers do not line up the way they're supposed to. Could someone please just post some code I could copy and paste.

I'm really behind on all my work and I just don't have time to learn all the code from scratch right now.

Brett

Comment: @ADDENDUM I've tried pasting your code into Latexit and it does not work. Again I have to reiterate I do not have the time or capacity to learn all the code right now with all the work I've got lined up. I would appreciate if someone were to look at the picture I've posted and paste in a simple code that would do the job. For now.

Comment: It works. The code works in Sharelatex. Thanks @Steven B. Segletes
It doesn't work in Latexit though.

Brett