# Displaying the complete Long division

Tags: math-mode, formatting, displaystyle

I want to display a long division procedure as illustrated.  [image]

I did search but couldn't find what I'm looking for. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375983/long-division-help, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/374754/noob-latexit-long-division, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131125/better-way-to-display-long-division/131131#131131, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395703/more-on-formatting-of-long-division, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With the package `longdivision`, you obtain almost the desired output (but as a French, I don't known this strange notation, see the documentation of the package `xlop` about *division* for the French notation).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longdivision}
\begin{document}
    \intlongdivision{12345}{13}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) Please edit it a bit so that the output fits the OP's picture fully (i.e. it should be 11700 instead of 117 in the third line).

Comment: @JouleV It’s why I say "you obtain almost the desired output" and "I don’t known this strange notation" (In France, we use other notation). I don’t known is my answer is perfect. If not, is this a bug of the `longdivision` package?

Comment: @quark67, thank you. I wonder why this is not working if I want to do the long division of  -37/44. My aim is to display that and write the continued fraction expansion.

Comment: @Fib1123 The package `longdivision` doesn't handle negative numbers. You can use the command `longdivision{37}{44}` instead `intlongdivision{37}{44}`, this give a continued fraction expansion, but I don't known if the displayed output is what you want (decimal numbers in the continued fraction expansion, in French notation, there are not decimal numbers in the continued fraction expansion).