# Elementary Long Division Template

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I am looking for a program that correctly spaces
the procedure of long division we all did in 
elementary school.

As minimal example I have but still have
trouble with spacing and suppose I 
wanted to put in subtraction symbols, I
find I have no room.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
$\begin{tabular}{r@{}l@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}l@{}c@{}}
  &        & & & &  && \\
  &        & &.&1&8 & &  \\ \cline{2-7} \\ [-12.3pt]
   11&\big )&2&.&0&0&0& \\ 
  &             &1&  1& & & &  \\ \cline{3-5} 
  &             & &9&0& & &  \\ 
  &             & &8&8& & &     \\ \cline{4-6} 
  &             & & &2&0& &  \\ 
  &             & & &1&1& & \\ \cline{5-6} 
  &             & & & &9& &
 \end{tabular}$
 \end{center}

 \end{document}
```

The decimal point is causing a spacing problem.
I am finding little material on this on the web. This outputs

[image]

There must a better more versatile way to do this?

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Vertical addition and multiplication and long division](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/45304) or better, perhaps is [Displaying the complete Long division](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/476518)

Comment: For dealing with the period, you might enclose it in braces `{.}` to avoid possible unexpected spacing, and then insert `\phantom{.}` in the appropriate position in the "next" line.

Comment: Yes , there is no easy answer to this!

Comment: I don't know this way of doing divisions. In which country is this algorithm being learned?

Comment: @AndréC -- This used to be the method taught in the U.S.  I attended elementary school in Baltimore, and my mother was a second-grade teacher.  But I don't know whether it's still taught this way.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you very much. Do you have an internet link that allows me to understand this way of doing divisions?

Comment: @AndréC -- No, I don't have any link; it's just embedded in my brain.  This question ([Displaying the complete Long 
division](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/476518/579)) shows the formatting, but doesn't explain how to interpret it.  Briefly, the answer is the number shown at the top.  The lines below the dividend are, successively, the product of the integer in the answer times the divisor, a rule, and the remainder from subtracting the partial product from the dividend,  To take the next step, "bring down" the next digit from the dividend, and repeat.  (I hope this makes sense.)

Comment: @AndréC -- An explanation of this method is given in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division

Comment: @barbarabeeton thanks you very much.