# How to display the greatest common divisor by long division?

Tags: formatting

How can I draw the following scheme?

[image]

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/476518/displaying-the-complete-long-division or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131125/better-way-to-display-long-division

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Better way to display long division?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131125/better-way-to-display-long-division)

Comment: @albert It is not duplicate post. \intlongdivision gives the entire division process. My question is regarding the greatest common divisor.

Comment: If it's not a duplicate, can you please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what you have tried so far? Posting only an image is of little help

Comment: @AlessandroCuttin I tried \intlongdivision first and then I looked at polynom package and tried \polylonggcd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\newcommand\ml[1]{\multicolumn{1}{l}{#1}}
\newcommand\lparen{\mkern1mu(\mkern1mu}
\newcommand\rparen{\mkern1mu)\mkern1mu}
\newcommand\pp{\phantom{\lparen}}

\begin{document}
\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
\begin{array}{ *{11}{r} }
   198 & \rparen & 360 & \lparen & \ml{1} \\
   &&        198 & \pp \\
\cmidrule{3-4}
   && 162 & \rparen & 198 & \lparen & \ml{1} \\
   &&&& 162 & \pp \\
\cmidrule{5-6}
   &&&& 36 & \rparen & 162 & \lparen & \ml{4} \\
   &&&&&& 144 & \pp \\
\cmidrule{7-8}
   &&&&&& 18 & \rparen & 36 & \lparen & \ml{2} \\
   &&&&&&&& 36 & \pp\\
\cmidrule{9-10}
   &&&&&&&& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\times}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, It works.

Answer (score 1):

This is typical example for doing macros recursive:

```
\def\divi #1)#2/#3=#4{#1)%
   \vtop{\hbox{#2}\hbox{#3}\smallskip\hrule width1.5em\smallskip\hbox{#4}}}
\def\0{\phantom0}

\divi 198)360(1/190={%
          \divi 162)198(1/162={%
                    \divi \036)162(4/144={%
                               \divi \018)36(2/36={%
                                          $\0\times$}}}}

\bye
```